# How to integrate Realtime Map Tracking in Flutter Project similar to Uber, Ola and Zomato

Tags: flutter, real-time, real-time-updates

I want to integrate Realtime Map Tracking for delivery purposes in my Flutter Project. This is a grocery project. I have followed many Articles but the performance of the Map is not smooth. It takes time to update the Map. Please share the solution if anybody has implemented Map for Realtime tracking.

I have tried following solutions but the prformance is not good as Uber or Ola have:-

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-google-map-with-live-location-tracking-uber-style-12da38771829

https://medium.com/flutter-community/implement-real-time-location-updates-on-google-maps-in-flutter-235c8a09173e

https://github.com/igaurab/user_location_plugin